# Routing error with python flask search app

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get a simple search function going with my flask app. I have the following code that kicks off the search

```
<form action="/search" method=post>
 <input type=text name=search value="{{ request.form.search }}"></br>
 <div class="actions"><input type=submit value="Search"></div>
</form>
```

This hooks in with my search/controllers.py script that looks like this

```
@search.route('/search/')
@search.route('/search/<query>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(query=None):
    es = current_app.config.get("es")

    q = {"query":{ "multi_match":{"fields":["name","tags","short_desc","description"],"query":query,"fuzziness":"AUTO"}}}
    matches = es.search('products', 'offerings', body=q)
    return render_template('search/results.html', services=matches['_source'])
```

Unfortunately whenever I actually search I get a routing error:

> FormDataRoutingRedirect: A request was sent to this URL (http://localhost:8080/search) but a redirect was issued automatically by the routing system to "http://localhost:8080/search/". The URL was defined with a trailing slash so Flask will automatically redirect to the URL with the trailing slash if it was accessed without one. Make sure to directly send your POST-request to this URL since we can't make browsers or HTTP clients redirect with form data reliably or without user interaction. Note: this exception is only raised in debug mode

I tried changing the method to `methods=['POST']` but it made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `url_for('index')` to generate the correct url for the action.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('index') }}">
```

---

Currently, you're submitting to the url without the trailing `/`. Flask redirects this to the route with the trailing `/`, but POST data doesn't survive redirects on many browsers, so Flask is warning you about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, your form is posting to /search but your handler is set up for /search/. Make them the same.